# Is it possible to retrieve digitally signed pdf files that were wrongly merged?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I made a mistake and merged multiple digitally signed pdf files into one. Is there a possibility that I can retrieve the original pdf files with the signatures from that one file?

Unfortunately, it has to be from the merged file, as there are legal matters, about my job.
Thank you

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible that you can retrieve the original PDFs with still valid signatures.

Merging PDFs completely changes the data structures from the source files. E.g.:

- Indirect objects in PDFs are numbered, usually starting with number 1 in a PDF; as in the merged PDF each imported indirect object needs a different number, most of those numbers will have changed in the course of merging to prevent collisions.
- Numerous objects from the input PDFs are merged into a single one, e.g. the page trees are merged into one, the form definitions are merged into a single one, ...
- Much of the document-level information from the source PDFs (like the metadata) is dropped.
- The PDF standard allows different ways to represent the exactly identical information. E.g. line endings, white spaces in general, object cross reference types, order of entries in dictionaries, ...
- ...

A digital signature, on the other hand, requires the PDF revision it signs to remain byte-by-byte the original to remain valid.

Thus, it is virtually impossible to recreate the originally signed PDF revisions from the merged files.

One exception: If your PDF merger happens to merge using incremental updates, the first of the merged PDFs probably can be extracted from the merged PDF. I'm not aware of a PDF merger, though, that by default uses incremental updates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. That was what I thought, but had to ask to be certain.